# Proper Map initialization in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to properly initalize a map for a struct.

```
struct Tile
{
char character;
map<char,Tile*> neighbors;
Tile(char c)
{
        character = c;
        neighbors = new map<char,Tile*>();
    }
};
```

When I try to initialize it there I get:

error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::map' and 'std::map*')

note: candidate is:|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h|264|note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = char; _Tp = boardTile*; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h|264|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::map*' to 'const std::map&'|

Comment: You have `map<char,boardTile*> neighbors;`, what's there to initialize? You want to add a key-value pair.

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#.  There is nothing to `new` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
map<char,boardTile*> neighbors;
```

does not to be allocated dynamically, so discard this:

```
neighbors = new map<char,boardTile*>();
```

I mean `neighbors` is not a pointer, it's just a map. You will need `new` for `boardTile*`, which is a pointer.

Comment: When I was not trying to allocate it I get a runtime error when I try to add in an entry

Comment: Make a minimal complete example with that then @DhruvKarunakaran.

Comment: @DhruvKarunakaran Then your problem has nothing to do with declaring the map.  It may have everything to do with that `boardTile` pointer you have there  and how (and why) you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

`neighbors` is not a pointer so

```
neighbors = new map<char,boardTile*>();
```

tries to assign a pointer to a `map<char,boardTile*>` which is incorrect.  You can use

```
Tile(char c) : character(c) {}
```

For your constructor.

Comment: Ok, I see, but OP wanted to add one entry in the map, which is why he/she mixed up what to `new`.